# Discord.py - How do I edit an old embed message that is no longer in my bot code

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have an embed message that is only made up of 1 image and 1 color, it's a banner of my rules chat. I want to edit this banner but the code I used to upload it doesn't exist anymore, how can I edit it anyway?

I wanted a good explanation and some example code.

Answer (score 2):

Try using discord.Message.edit() function. You can fetch the message using fetch_message(ID), where ID is the message's ID.

```
@Bot.command()
async def EditMessage(ctx, ID:int):
    message = discord.fetch_message(ID)
    await message.edit()#What you want to edit
```

## Edit

If I understood well, you need the code for only one message, so you should do like this:

```
from discord import fetch_message, Embed, Color

@Bot.command()
async def EditThatMessage(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete() #So that nobody will see about the edit
    message = fetch_message(ID) #ID is your message's ID
    await message.edit(embed = Embed(title = "", description = "", color = Color.random()))
```

Then you should stop your bot, delete the command, and restart the bot.

## In conclusion

If it works, please accept my answer.
Otherwise write me what went wrong in the comments.